# `numpy.tile()` sorts automatically - is there an alternative?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'd like to initialize a `pandas` DataFrame so that I can populate it with multiple time series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase
dt_rng = pd.date_range(start = pd.tseries.tools.to_datetime('2012-12-31'), 
                       end   = pd.tseries.tools.to_datetime('2014-12-28'), 
                       freq  = 'D')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = xrange(len(dt_rng) * 10),
                  columns = ['product', 'dt', 'unit_sales'])
df.product = sorted(np.tile([chr for chr in ascii_uppercase[:10]], len(dt_rng)))
df.dt = np.tile(dt_rng, 10)
df.unit_sales = np.random.random_integers(0, 25, len(dt_rng) * 10)
```

However, when I check the first few values of `df.dt`, I see that all values in the field have already been sorted, e.g.
`df.dt[:10]` yields `2012-12-31` ten times.
I'd like to have this output to be `2012-12-31`, `2013-01-01`, ..., `2013-01-08`, `2013-01-09` (first ten values).

In general, I'm looking for behavior similar to `R`'s "recycling".

Comment: When I try your code, it fails when it tries to create `df`.

Comment: Try `np.tile()`?  Basically the same as `repeat` but with different ordering.

Comment: @JohnE: I used both `np.tile(dt_rng, 10)` and `np.repeat(dt_rng, 10)`, and they both return sorted output. I don't want the output to be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `reduce()` and the `append()` method of a `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex`object did the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase
dt_rng = pd.date_range(start = pd.tseries.tools.to_datetime('2012-12-31'), 
                       end   = pd.tseries.tools.to_datetime('2014-12-28'), 
                       freq  = 'D')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = xrange(len(dt_rng) * 10),
                  columns = ['product', 'dt', 'unit_sales'])
df.product = sorted(np.tile([chr for chr in ascii_uppercase[:10]], len(dt_rng)))
df.dt = reduce(lambda x, y: x.append(y), [dt_rng] * 10)
df.unit_sales = np.random.random_integers(0, 25, len(dt_rng) * 10)
```